# Script with parameter

Tags: linux, bash

I supossed to make a script that given an number it count to 0, I managed to do this and it's working:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -n "type a number: "
read number; echo
while [ $number -ge 0 ]; do
echo -n "$number"
number=$((number-1))
done
echo
```

Well, I changed it because I need to pass the number by an parameter ex: "./script 5" and it must show the countdown till 0, but its getting in looping. I kind new on all it script/stack what Im doing wrong?

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$*" = "" ]; then
echo
echo "not correct"
echo "must be a int number"
echo
exit
fi

while [ "$1" -ge 0 ]; do
echo "$1"
cont='expr $1-1' 
done
echo
```

Comment: I'm not sure that an issue that surrounds modifying a different variable than the one you test to determine whether to terminate your loop is an issue likely to be helpful to others, and thus a useful knowledgebase addition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're always using `[ "$1" -ge 0 ]` as your condition, but the value you actually modify/update is `cont`, not `$1`. (Moreover, you modify it based on the value of `$1`, which isn't changing, so you only ever set `$cont` to one less than the original value of `$1`).

Consider:

```
#!/bin/bash
[[ $1 ]] || { printf '%s\n' "First argument must be an integer" >&2; exit 1; }
for ((i=$1; i>=0; i--)); do
    echo "$i"
done
```

...and note, among the various changes:

- We're consistently referring to the first argument passed as `$1`, rather than also sometimes referring to it as `$*`
- When we select a variable to modify (`$i`, here, rather than `$cont`), we use that same variable in our tests, and also as the source for modification in the loop.
- Using `expr` for math is antiquated; POSIX sh allows `$(( ))` to create a math context, and bash extends this to also allow C-style `for` loops in a math context.